# Javascript oop instances

Tags: javascript, oop, three.js

I am developing with Javascript oop and Observer pattern. 
In the first method model g is put inside mesh and mesh inside scene. We can find now our g model in scene.children. In the second method in intersected[i].object we can find our model g. The problem is that if I modify a property of intersected[i].object it is not reflected to the model g.

```
g = new GeometryModel();
tjsv = new ThreeJSView(document.getElementById('maincanvas'), g);


GeometryModel.prototype.populateScene = function(scene) {
var i;
for (i = 0; i < this.geometries.length; i++) {
 var g = this.geometries[i];//<-----  g is the model
 var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: g.color, transparent: g.transparent, opacity: g.opacity });

 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(g, material);
 this.addLabels(g, mesh);
 scene.add(mesh);

 if (g.lineWidth > 0) {
      var egh = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, g.lineColor );
      egh.material.linewidth = g.lineWidth;
      scene.add( egh );
   }
  }
}





ThreeJSView.prototype.selectByRaycaster = function(x, y){
var i;
var intersected;
var mouse = {x: (x / this.width) * 2 - 1, y: 1 - (y / this.height) * 2};
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, this.camera);
intersected = raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children);
console.log();

for ( var i = 0; i < intersected.length; i++ ) {

      if (intersected[i].object instanceof THREE.Mesh){

          intersected[i].object.selected = true;// I modify my model 
          changed = true;
          console.log( intersected[i].object);
      }
}

  console.log(this.model);//my model but here there are no modify!


 if (changed)
   this.model.notifyListeners(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that g is referring to geometry while intersected[i].object is referring to an Object3D - different objects.

You probably need to write something like this:
    intersected[i].object.**geometry**.selected = true;